# Get all Ports On Server BY PHP Code

Tags: php, sockets, port

Good day.I was trying to find a php code from where i can get all ports on sever side.The reason is that im using a shared server,shared server does not let me to execute any cmd command and how funny and pathetic it would be on google i did not find any php code which will do this except this one.

```
$host = 'stackoverflow.com';
$ports = array(21, 25, 80, 81, 110, 443, 3306);

foreach ($ports as $port)
{
    $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);

    if (is_resource($connection))
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' ' . '(' . getservbyport($port, 'tcp') . ') is open.</h2>' . "\n";

        fclose($connection);
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' is not responding.</h2>' . "\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is that i want to open a socket and accept a socket connection from android but whatever port i try to open,it says that port is in use and by this code im not gettin all ports but only this ones

```
array(21, 25, 80, 81, 110, 443, 3306);
```

So my quesiton is there any php code which will return me all ports on server with status are they in use or no.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to iterate through all 65.6k ports?

```
$host = "somedomain.com";
$port = 1;
while ($port <= 65535){
    // Check current port # here
    // Have fun waiting for the loop to complete.

   $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);

    if (is_resource($connection))
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' ' . '(' . getservbyport($port, 'tcp') . ') is open.</h2>' . "\n";

        fclose($connection);
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' is not responding.</h2>' . "\n";
    }

    $port++;
}
```

Comment: haha now thats what i love :D unfortunatally i want as the dumb customer care on server says that they cant give me some ports,so i must find it by my self....damn this im not the gypsy

Comment: I'm not sure what your needs are, but it may be worth the money to invest in a VPS for ~$15/mo.

Comment: you see the problem is the usage,im paying same exact money for shared server,but the VPS have limit on storage,whereas the shared server does not,and i need unlimited disk space for a hugement project....thats the problem

Comment: How much space is required?

Comment: Um unlimited...its based on users.Users can post unlimited images to my server,and images shall not be deleted under any circumstances....:( so yeah unlimited....

Comment: Hmm.  Ok.  Hopefully you can monetize it somehow and get a server that you have control over.

Comment: I hope so too...as for now the issue being raised upon me,See im creating an platform where users can ask us to make images for them and can ask to redesign their images,which sooner will be something like freelancer for designers and later for developers and etc,so yeah i definatally need to monetize and i defintally need to use sockets as i will have fully chat inside the app